# Xperia J and 512 MB RAM

Tags: ram, sony, utilization, sony-xperia

I asked a question in the [Sony forum](http://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-J/512MB-RAM/m-p/377567#U377567), but I did not get a clear answer. My Xperia J has only 380MB of RAM, and in white paper is written that the device has 512MB of RAM. What other components utilize the remaining memory?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about software, programming or so.

Comment: Sony forum support agent send me here with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAM usage is mentioned in [this](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/03/30/learn-about-the-technical-differences-between-gingerbread-and-ics/) article on the difference between Gingerbread and ICS.

*"Out of our 512MB RAM, about a third is used for functions that require a dedicated memory slot to operate fast enough. For example, this is the case for certain multimedia functions."*

- You can not free this memory

Best regards,
Carl Johansson

Comment: Thanks for this article. I do not want to free this memory. I'm writing an article about the Xperia J which is to be very technical and I need information of high level of expertise.